# Android MySQL Database - ListView [Open Activity]

Tags: android, mysql, listview, onclick

I have a list, each item on the list contains "merchant name" and "merchant id". "merchant name" and "merchant id” are retrieved from MySQL database. I wish to go to another activity when item inside the list is clicked. I don't know how to get the index and retrieve all the information about merchant to send to the next activity. 
[This is the next activity I wish to go, I want show all these information.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m14tl.png)

Can anyone tell me how to do this

Answer (score 0):

Use **OnItemClickListener** for listview

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id)
{
 // add your codes.     
 // int **position** gives you the index.
}
});
```